# Firebase Analytics Xamarin iOS - Debug View

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I know this question has been asked earlier many times but those answers doesn't seems to work now. I have a Xamarin iOS App, Firebase Analytics logs well in simulator but when running in actual device I get the below error:

In Simulator it logs the below
2020-08-12 20:42:24.471571+0400[5016:66465] 6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

But in actual iPhone 11 it logs the below :O

default 19:01:12.272016+0400    iOS 6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

I have added extra mlaunch arguments in iOS project settings under Run -> Config (--argument=-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled) and mtouch arguments in iOS build(--argument=-FIRDebugEnabled) and also I did different permutations of both commands also, but it doesn't seem to log anything in Debug view. I cannot see my device in the developer console.

I am using the below
Nuget package ver - Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics(6.0.4)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi , if only set mtouch arguments in iOS build , whehter it work?

Comment: Hi, I tried with both --argument=-FIRDebugEnabled
--argument=-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
in only iOS build mtouch command doesn't seem to work. I still get the same log default 19:01:12.272016+0400 iOS 6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

Comment: Okey, whether the [Linker Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#linker-behavior) select the Don't Link to check whehter it works?

Comment: Doesn't work if I change to Don't link I am getting build errors. :|

Comment: Okey , how about [link all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#link-all-assemblies)  ? It seems used with mtouch.

Comment: Crashes the app on launch :| Only Link SDK frameworks work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems that Firebase Analytics Debug View for Xamarin iOS is really buggy and may work or not with no particular reason. I spent a week trying to debug events for Xamarin and Unity platforms (both Android and iOS) and while it worked perfectly well on Unity Android and iOS and on Xamarin Android, Xamarin iOS could work one day and stop working another day without any changes. In that case my advice is to Debug via StreamView (Realtime) menu just above DebugView. Looks like it always works